# How to output 2 numbers of valid loss into a csv file?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file in this format:

```
| epoch  96 |     0/  184 batches | ms/batch  3.25 | s_loss 0.01193 0.01195 | w_loss 0.01237 0.01209
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end epoch  96 | valid loss 5.98355 5.91889 | lr 0.00028756|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| epoch  97 |     0/  184 batches | ms/batch  3.27 | s_loss 0.01372 0.01382 | w_loss 0.01456 0.01428
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end epoch  97 | valid loss 6.12931 5.99851 | lr 0.00028181|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| epoch  98 |     0/  184 batches | ms/batch  3.22 | s_loss 0.01338 0.01345 | w_loss 0.01514 0.01448
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end epoch  98 | valid loss 6.03077 5.97339 | lr 0.00027618|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| epoch  99 |     0/  184 batches | ms/batch  3.10 | s_loss 0.01365 0.01367 | w_loss 0.01389 0.01351
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end epoch  99 | valid loss 6.05937 5.97509 | lr 0.00027065|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| epoch 100 |     0/  184 batches | ms/batch  3.33 | s_loss 0.01315 0.01326 | w_loss 0.01357 0.01273
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end epoch 100 | valid loss 6.02757 5.98502 | lr 0.00026525|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to extract the epoch number and two numbers next to the valid loss. The first represents the valid sentence loss, and the second one represents the valid word loss. I want to save these values to a CSV file with three columns: 'Epoch', 'Valid Sentence Loss', and 'Valid Word Loss.' Here is what I have tried:

```
import re
import csv

# Input and output file paths
input_file_path = 'text.txt'
output_file_path = 'output.csv'

# Read content
with open(input_file_path, 'r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()

# Extract information
data = []
for line in lines:
    match_epoch = re.search(r'\| end epoch (\d+) \| valid loss (\d+\.\d+) (\d+\.\d+)', line)
    if match_epoch:
        epoch = int(match_epoch.group(1))
        s_loss, w_loss = map(float, match_epoch.groups()[1:])
        data.append((epoch, s_loss, w_loss))

# Write to a CSV file
with open(output_file_path, 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Epoch', 'Valid Sentence Loss', 'Valid Word Loss'])
    csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

The output:

```
Epoch,Valid Sentence Loss,Valid Word Loss
100,6.02757,5.98502
```

This is what I want:

```
Epoch,Valid Sentence Loss,Valid Word Loss
96,5.98355,5.91889
97,6.12931,5.99851
98,6.03077,5.97339
99,6.05937,5.97509
100,6.02757,5.98502
```

Comment: When the number is 2-digit, there is an extra space. Try `re.search(r'\| end epoch\s+(\d+) .....`

Comment: Alternatively, just use `.split()` and grab elements by number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. In the future, please make a [mre], which will help catch basic mistakes like this. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: The code I provide is reproducible ?

Comment: @user Yes, but it's not minimal. You don't need to output to a CSV to reproduce the problem, you can just `print(match_epoch)`. You also don't need all the hyphens in the data.

Comment: `re.split(r"\s+", row)[3]` will give you epoch for rows that start with "| end epoch ". Similarly you can use indexes 7 and 8 to get the other values.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to accomplish this. Can create and break down a list:

```py
import re


input = """| epoch  96 |     0/  184 batches | ms/batch  3.25 | s_loss 0.01193 0.01195 | w_loss 0.01237 0.01209
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end epoch  96 | valid loss 5.98355 5.91889 | lr 0.00028756|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| epoch  97 |     0/  184 batches | ms/batch  3.27 | s_loss 0.01372 0.01382 | w_loss 0.01456 0.01428
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end epoch  97 | valid loss 6.12931 5.99851 | lr 0.00028181|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| epoch  98 |     0/  184 batches | ms/batch  3.22 | s_loss 0.01338 0.01345 | w_loss 0.01514 0.01448
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end epoch  98 | valid loss 6.03077 5.97339 | lr 0.00027618|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| epoch  99 |     0/  184 batches | ms/batch  3.10 | s_loss 0.01365 0.01367 | w_loss 0.01389 0.01351
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end epoch  99 | valid loss 6.05937 5.97509 | lr 0.00027065|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| epoch 100 |     0/  184 batches | ms/batch  3.33 | s_loss 0.01315 0.01326 | w_loss 0.01357 0.01273
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| end epoch 100 | valid loss 6.02757 5.98502 | lr 0.00026525|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"""

lines = [
    [
        re.sub("[^0-9. ]+", "", y).strip().split()
        for y in x[2:-1].split("|")
        if y.strip()[:9] == "end epoch" or y.strip()[:10] == "valid loss"
    ]
    for x in input.split("\n")
    if x[:11] == "| end epoch"
]

csv_out = "Epoch,Valid Sentence Loss,Valid Word Loss"

for x in lines:
    csv_out += f"\n{x[0][0]},{x[1][0]},{x[1][1]}"

print(csv_out)
```

Output:

```
Epoch,Valid Sentence Loss,Valid Word Loss
96,5.98355,5.91889
97,6.12931,5.99851
98,6.03077,5.97339
99,6.05937,5.97509
100,6.02757,5.98502
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want to extract the epoch number and two numbers next to the valid loss. ..."*

Here is an example, where *s* is the text.

```java
d = []
for l in s.splitlines():
    if l.startswith('| end epoch'):
        s = l[2:].split(' | ')[:2]
        s = (s[0][9:].lstrip(), *s[1][10:].strip().split())
        d.append(','.join(s))
```

Output

```
96,5.98355,5.91889
97,6.12931,5.99851
98,6.03077,5.97339
99,6.05937,5.97509
100,6.02757,5.98502
```